# How to delete a file from local disk in UWP

Tags: uwp, local-storage, local-files

I am trying to delete a picture stored in my local folder in my UWP application. However, I am not very sure how to do it.

The picture file is located under "Pictures", which I think the path is:

**C:\Users\UserName\Pictures**

I have written a set of code which I believe is to retrieve the file... however, I am not sure how to continue from here.

```
StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
string name = "deletetest.jpg";
StorageFile manifestFile = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(name);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add this lines.DeleteAsync will delete the file.

```
 StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
 string name = "deletetest.jpg";
 StorageFile manifestFile = await picturesFolder.GetFileAsync(name);
 await manifestFile.DeleteAsync();
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much!